# simplifying a basic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $$3\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (2k - 3)+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (4 − 5k)$$

Can someone show all steps to simplify this? The answer should simplify down to the sum of $k-5$ I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually very simple:
$$3\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-3)+\sum_{k=1}^n (4-5k)$$
Note that: $c\cdot \sum_{k=1}^n (f(k))\equiv \sum_{k=1}^n (c\cdot f(k))$, where $c$ is a constant:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n 3(2k-3)+\sum_{k=1}^n (4-5k)=\sum_{k=1}^n (6k-9)+\sum_{k=1}^n (4-5k)$$
Note that the limits of the sums are the same:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (6k-9)+\sum_{k=1}^n (4-5k)=\sum_{k=1}^n (6k-9+4-5k)=\sum_{k=1}^n (k-5)$$